# Strange Results when converting int to LPCTSTR with sstream

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have declared the following method to convert an integer to a LPCTSTR for use in an MFC application.

```
LPCTSTR CTCPServerDlg::Int32ToLPCTSTR(int i32) {
    std::wostringstream ss;
    ss << i32;
    LPCTSTR res = ss.str().c_str();
    MessageBox(ss.str().c_str()); // Correctly shows value.
    MessageBox(res); // Nothing shown.
    return res;
}
```

As commented above, the first message box correctly shows the integer I pass into the i32 parameter.  The second messagebox displays nothing (or I presume invisible characters).  When calling the function like so:

```
MessageBox(Int32ToLPCTSTR(3));
```

I get some strange character.  I think it's a chinese symbol.  I understand that Unicode and ANSI with different types in Windows can confuse the best of us, but the return value of ss.str().c_str() should assign properly to the LPCTSTR res variable I declare right?  Furthermore, when attempting to insert the created LPCTSTR into a CEdit control, I get even more unknown chinese characters, all different from before.

Apologies if I am being stupid, help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string returned by `ss.str()` returned *by value*, and if you don't store it then it is temporary and will be destructed once the expression is done, leaving you with a pointer to a string that no longer exists. This will of course lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you try to dereference that stray pointer.

Comment: Understood, how would you suggest solving this problem?

Comment: @LJPark Use `std::wstring` as far as possible, don't get a pointer until you actually need it. So instead of having a `Int32ToLPCTSTR` function, you have an `Int32ToWstring` function, that returns a string by value. Then you can do e.g. `Int32ToWstring(3).c_str()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`res` is a dangling pointer. The `str()` function of `wostringstream` returns a new `std::wstring` *by value.* This means that it's a temporary.

The `std::wstring` function `c_str()` returns a pointer to the internal buffer of the string. That pointer is only valid as long as the string itself remains valid (and unmodified).

This together means that `res` becomes dangling as soon as its initialisation ends.

The entire interface of your function looks flawed. To return a `LPCTSTR`, it will have to allocate memory for the returned string. But this means you'll be returning a raw pointer to dynamically-allocated memory, which leads to leaks, double-deletion errors etc. Simply change your function to return a `std::wstring` (or `_tstring` if you *really* want to keep using `TCHAR`). You can then obtain a `LPCTSTR` from it whenever necessary by calling `c_str()`.

Even better, I suggest you drop the use of `TCHAR` altogether. Are you *ever* going to build your application for single-byte character strings or multi-byte character strings? I'd assume not, in which case you can simply use `std::wstring`, `wchar_t` and the appropriate functions throughout, and make your life easier.